# Include scripts on sub page with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I understand that I can handle the `pageinit()` or other events to execute JavaScript for a newly loaded page, but that requires me to have the actual JavaScript exist or be reference from the *Main page*.

How can I include scripts at the bottom of a sub page, and have it execute on load of the page?

I tried to set the sub page's function to a global variable (I know it's dirty), but even that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery mobile -loading dynamic pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141284/jquery-mobile-loading-dynamic-pages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer myself.  It looks like the JavaScript on the child page needs to be inside the "page", not just inside the body tag:

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-title="My Subpage">
        <p>Awesome content!</p>
        <!-- DO put your JavaScript here. -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('This works');
        </script>
    </div>
    <!-- DON'T put your JavaScript here. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('This doesn't work');
    </script>
</body>
```

**Pro tip:**
It looks like any script inside the body but outside the "Page" element, **even on the main page** (first loaded page), don't get executed!!!  So even if you disabled the AJAX loading/transitions of jQuery mobile, the default page rendering still kills those scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you want JQM loaded needs to be inside the  element, as described in their documentation.

I personally noticed memory-hogs and leaks when loading jscript this way, it seemed it never correctly removed it thus creating duplicates if this page was loaded over and over again. I finally moved that jscript to the main page, and my problems were gone!
Of course this could be related to the code itself, but it was doing a lot of event binding/unbinding and I was never sure JQ actually removed blank references.

Anyway, just my $.02...