# jQuery mobile passing parameter from one page to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am currently using a form to navigate and pass form parameters from one one page to another and through a query string.

`FirstPage` form code

```
<form name="input" action="new_page.html" method="get">
Username: <input type="text" name="user" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In the new page I am trying to get the query-string value using `document.URL`. When the old page directs to the new page only the body contents of the new page are executed. The script files are not executed in the new page. Thus, I am not able to grab the query string values in the new page.

The process of passing parameters through form from one page to another works well for a regular HTML page, but does not work in case of jQuery Mobile.

Can any one suggest me a better way of passing parameters from one jQuery Mobile page to another. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your scripts not executing when you change pages: [jQueryMobile page events not firing when navigating to a different html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095887/jquerymobile-page-events-not-firing-when-navigating-to-a-different-html-page/8097495#8097495)

jQuery Mobile uses AJAX to pull new pages into the DOM, which is something you'll have to get used to for creating jQuery Mobile websites. This means that code that is supposed to run on `document.ready` or `window.load` should be bound to other events like: `pagecreate`, `pageshow`, `pageinit`. Here's jQuery Mobile's documentation on events (which can be quite enlightening): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html (Note that page-events start about half-way down).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding passing querystring parameters in JQM, have a look at [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238762/passing-parameters-to-a-page-id-in-jquery-mobile/8295488#8295488) with code samples.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect from a jquery mobile page the new page is loaded using ajax, so JS for the new page won't work using the $(document).ready();

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      //your awesome JS here won't work!
});
```

so use this instead:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit',function(event){
         //the same JS here will work!

});
```

Now your JS should work (at least did for me!).
for further info go [here.](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html)
Hope this helps!