# How to pass values from one page to another in jquerymobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery mobile passing parameter from one page to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349388/jquery-mobile-passing-parameter-from-one-page-to-another)

I need to pass values from one page html to another html page. what is the best way to pass the value. can anyone explain  me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass the variables through forms, urls and session. You can use all the methods you use in existing web applications to pass data from 1 page to another. or you can utilize the local storage of HTML5 which is a modern and faster way of storing the secure data

```
localStorage.lastname="Smith";
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Last name: "+ localStorage.lastname;
```

You can find more information about HTML5's local storage on the following link

http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html5 local or session storage api to store the small data across the pages.

To set the value on session storage

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

and to get the value

`sessionStorage.getItem('key');`